# Search for alias not finding files

Tags: finder, search, alias

I am running Yosemite on a Mac Pro Mid 2010.

When I moved to an SSD for my boot drive, I started using Symbolic Linking so some apps would store their data on a regular HD. So, for example, I go to my library folder and in Application support there's an Evernote alias. It works flawlessly, and I've done this for many apps that don't offer an easy way to store data elsewhere.

Now, my data drive is approaching its limit, and I have a larger drive coming. I'd like to be able to redirect the links to the new drive, and tried searching for "kind is alias" but that doesn't show the links. The Evernote alias doesn't get found in a search, nor do any others I know I've set up.

TL;DR - How do I perform a search to show me Alias files I've created? A normal search, even for alias files I've just created, don't show up in a search.

Comment: Did you use the Alias command from the finder, or did you use ln -s in the terminal? Unix symbolic links are not quite the same as an Alias although they serve similar purposes

Comment: In search, I indicated Kind is Alias. (in Get info, the Kind shows "Alias" for the one I know of)

Comment: When you created the link though, how did you do so?

Comment: I installed an app. SymbolicLinker.service, I can click on a file and under services I see "Make symbolic link".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you use the Alias command from the finder when you created the links, or did you use ln -s in the terminal? Unix symbolic links are not quite the same as an Alias although they serve similar purposes. From the name of the service you installed, it's probably a good assumption they were using Unix symbolic links.

In that case, you'll probably want to use the [find](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) command in the terminal, e.g.: `find /Users/yourhome/Library/ -type l`

Assuming that [this](https://github.com/nickzman/symboliclinker) was the service you installed, it looks like they're calling [symlink](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/symlink.html) from the standard C libraries, which in turn is going to use Unix symlinks, and not Mac OS aliases.